# DataTable slow Loading of Data from Database

Tags: jquery, datatable

Hi guys need a help  i need to load 
 ***10 thousand data***
 from my database and here is my
Data table code how can i load my data FAST i read some

```
$('#example').dataTable({
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bSort": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bDestroy": false,
        "bJQueryUI": false,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
});
```

but i dont find the right solution 
to load fast a ***10,000 data*** from data base

Comment: Please tag appropriately. Which language? Which RDBMS? What is the volume of the database/source table?

Comment: @andrew - the website connected to your profile seems down....

Answer (score 1):

DataTables supports [server-side paging](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html) that is quite easy to implement and well documented on its web site. I have implemented the DataTables server-side paging with PetaPoco and Entity Framework against SQL Server databases. The web site provides some PHP examples as well.

In terms of scalability, I demonstrated in a blog post of mine on [Server-Side Paging with PetaPoco and DataTables](http://www.woodcp.com/2012/02/server-side-paging-with-petapoco-and-datatables/), along with a [GitHub reference implementation in .NET](https://github.com/tawman/PetaPocoPage), how you can easily support millions of rows with less than a second page response times.